# Identify mailserver running on remote box?

Tags: mail, mail-server

Hey guys I'm going through a hosting company that set up a mailserver and I am 
trying to identify the mailserver (Postfix, Sendmail, Exim?) so I can set up a Monit 
rule around it, but haven't had any luck. Is there a command to tell me what mail
is using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open an email sent from an account hosted by the mail server and view the headers, you should find it in there.

Comment: Yep, never thought of that...

Answer (score 2):

You can telnet to the host on port 25. For example:

> telnet mailserver 25

It will kick back the mail server and version number. To exit the telnet session just click QUIT.

Comment: The Telnet port will more than likely be blocked for security reasons. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet#Security

Comment: The telnet *port* will probably be closed, but the telnet *client application* will connect to whatever port you tell it to and allow you to converse with it interactively, so the above command connects to port 25.